# How to solve xslt syntax error when removing duplicated values

Tags: xml, xslt, syntax-error

I removing duplicated nodes in xml file, but i receive syntax error and have not ideas how to solve it

```xml
<xsl:variable name="list-asset-ids">
    <xsl:for-each select="ServiceContractRoot/RelatedContractLineItems">
        <asset id="{Asset/Id}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="list-asset-ids-2" select="exsl:node-set($list-asset-ids)"/>

<!--Syntax error here (in for-each )-->
<xsl:for-each select="$list-asset-ids-2/asset[not(@id=preceding-sibling::*/$list-asset-ids-2/asset/@id)]">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: @mzjn oh, i am so sorry. I mean I found solution how to remove repeated nodes, but I receive  syntax error

Comment: Surely you could provide a clue by telling us the error mesage?

Comment: You seem to be using XSLT 1.0 - so for removing duplicates look at the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Or, if your processor supports it, use the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, you can't use a variable reference `$list-asset-ids-2` on the right hand side of the `/` operator.

You can do so in XSLT 2.0, but it might not mean what you think it means. (Please, in XSLT questions, tell us which version you are using!)

It's not at all clear what you thought it might do, given that the variable holds an XML tree containing a bunch of `<asset>` elements.

So I can tell you what the error is, but I can't tell you how to correct it, since I have no idea what you were trying to achieve.